# Fact in Fiction

Tags: word-usage, semantics

Is a fact implied within fictional literature still a fact actually?

Imagine this real-life conversation:

> Person 1: "Does Deadpool have better healing abilities than Wolverine?"
>
> Person 2: "I don't know.  I will have to **fact**-check that."

In this situation, is it proper to refer to this piece of information as **fact**?

Comment: Yeah it's unusual for a fictional character to be aware of their own immateriality.

Comment: What do you mean by 'is it proper'?

Comment: Meaning, if I turn in a paper to a professor, am I going to get marked of for refering something in a fictional literature as fact.  (not actually the case, just trying to put it in context)

Comment: This seems to have little to do with English language. Maybe try this on writers.SE, literature.SE, or scifi.SE.

Comment: The root here is **usage** of the word fact (which is English), and it's validity of in this context.  Not sure how it has "little to with the English language", although the question still might be a fit for the other SE sites mentioned.

Comment: writersSE it should be. What if you post a German version on GermanSE on the same argument? or another language? Migrate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't see any real problem with using the word **fact** in this context. At the very least, it is logically valid. If Deadpool and Wolverine exist, then Deadpool can heal better than Wolverine. They certainly exist in the Marvel universe.

One may sometimes talk about facts in a fictional universe using the word **[canon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canon_%28fiction%29)**. While in some sense it means *official* (as opposed to *derivative*), I believe it can also mean *factual given the confines of the agreed-upon universe*.

Answer (score 2):

Interesting question. Such a statement is a fact within the context of its fictional universe(s) -- I see your question as more of whether or not you should reference the context in which such a statement is fact. Since Deadpool and Wolverine are completely fictional characters that cannot be confused with reality, the fictional context is implicit within the statement. If it was a statement using real characters or things within a fictional context (was Abraham Lincoln's bear bigger than Benjamin Franklin's T-Rex?), then it would probably be appropriate to explicitly define your context.

Answer (score 1):

OP is taking pedantry to extremes here. In Lit. Crit. contexts (which we can assume are usually written by people competent in English), it's perfectly normal to come across...

> ["Faustus is in fact..."](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22Faustus%20is%20in%20fact%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) *(171 hits in Google Books)*
>
> ["Othello is in fact..."](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22Faustus%20is%20in%20fact%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbo=1&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22Othello%20is%20in%20fact%22&oq=%22Othello%20is%20in%20fact%22&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_nf=1&gs_l=serp.3...60219.61603.4.62225.7.7.0.0.0.0.71.334.7.7.0.ymL_ALnCe2k&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=7dd15fed0098cd34) *(867 hits)*
>
> ["Macbeth is in fact..."](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22Faustus%20is%20in%20fact%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbo=1&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22Macbeth%20is%20in%20fact%22&oq=%22Macbeth%20is%20in%20fact%22&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_nf=1&gs_l=serp.3...14964.20073.10.20553.17.16.1.0.0.0.127.1058.15j1.18.0.BeaTm1PgE_4&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=7dd15fed0098cd34) *(751 hits)*

The term *"in fact"* usually introduces information the reader might either not be aware of, or be inclined to disagree with - but it's *information in context*. The context can be a fictional "world", just as much as the "real world".